# How to create parallel interactions in a sequence diagram using plantuml

Tags: uml, plantuml

Hi i want to make a uml diagram with some parallel interactions like [this](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-combined-fragment.html#operator-par), using plant uml.

But i don't know if it is possible to add the  dotted lines between the 'threads'. What i have so far is the following. `A` is sending something that is picked up and acted on by `b`, `c` and `d` at the same time. Is it possible to add dotted lines between `b`, `c` and `d`?

```
group par
  activate a
  a -> b: doSomething

  a -> c: doSomething

  a -> d: doSomething
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't an activity diagram be a better fit for parallel actions (as in using forks and joins)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add the `else` keyword to separate the threads :

```
par
  activate a
  a -> b
else
  a -> c
else
  a -> d
end
```

[image]